# testing REST web services in soapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying the write a groovy script which get the result from the response of the first testStep and use it into the next testStep. 
My web service returns the following response after a POST:

```
<Response xmlns="http://xxxxxx.xxx.xxxxx.xxx/cal-service/v1/users/">
   <individual_id>83ecf411-0e3b-4e6b-9bc4-d4b5f6efed54</individual_id>
</Response>
```

I am trying to grab the  and pass it to my next test in the test suite.

I am new with groovy and soapUI but what I started with is:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("messageExchange.responseContent")

def individualId = responseHolder.getNodeValue("individual_id")
log.info(individualId)
```

I am getting the following error when i run the test suite and it reaches the groovy script:

Comment: Think you forgot the error...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your error in you post, but to grab something from a request - here's how you do it. The groovy script will return the id from your request.

```
def id = context.expand( '${REST Test Request#ResponseAsXml#declare namespace ns1=\'http://lshlx082a.sys.cigna.com/cal-service/v1/users/'; //ns1:individual_id[1]}' )

return id;
```

Replace the "REST Test Request" part with the name of your REST test step.

NOTE: I tried this with my own namespace, so I might have cut-and-pasted your namespace and declarations incorrectly. But this is the general approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried it with no success. I have some REST test steps and i am trying to script my testing to automate the process. What is the general process to get an ID from a test step and pass it to the next one. Do I need to use property-transfer? Also my response from the rest service is JSON, how can I can I parse the response to verify I am getting the correct result using Groovy. Another question I have is when to use script assertion and write the groovy in there versus using Groovy Script??

Hopefully I made sense. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Generally, I don't use property transfer if I am moving data from one step to the other. In those cases, it is simpler to just get the data from the previous step to the next.

As for assertions, I put them in a separate step at the end, for readability. This will either be a Groovy step or an assertion step (4.5 version). For more on readable soap UI tests, see my blog post: [BDD with Soap UI](http://developingquality.blogspot.se/2011/11/bdd-with-soap-ui.html). 

As far as JSON goes, [this link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/json.html) might be something to start with.

Comment: Also, could you post or mail me the response from your service? Then I could most definitely help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Property transfer step to transfer values between responces